# How to perfor subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, struct

I want to assign one structure `A` to another structure `B` indexed:

```
B(3) = A;
```

while `A` having different fields than `B`. I want non existing fields automatically created and absent fields automatically ignored.

Is this possible in `Matlab`?

Comment: I don't think that's possible for structures. Perhaps defining a class and overriding [`subsasgn`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsasgn.html)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

You can use [fieldnames](https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/fieldnames.html) function, and assign each field value using a loop. The other fields will remaine unchanged.

**Example**

```
%defines input stract
a.f1 = 2; a.f2 = 3; a.f3 = 'str';
temp.f2=5; temp.f3 = 7; temp.f4 =1;
b(1) = temp; b(2) = temp; b(3) = temp;

%iterates over the fields of a and assigns their values into b
fields = fieldnames(a);
for ii = 1:numel(fields)
  b(3).(fields{ii}) = a.(fields{ii});
end
```

**Results**

before

```
a = 
f1: 2
f2: 3
f3: 'str'

b(3) = 
f2: 5
f3: 7
f4: 1
```

after

```
b(3)= 
f2: 3
f3: 'str'
f4: 1
f1: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  Ibezito beat me to pretty much the same answer by a minute or so...

I've done something similar with a function like this:

```
function B = mergeStruct(B,A,bIdx)
aFields = fieldnames(A);
for af = aFields';
    B(bIdx).(char(af)) = A.(char(af));
end
```

See this example:

```
>> B.a = 1;
>> B.b = 2;
>> A.b = 10;
>> A.c = 11;
>> B = mergeStruct(B,A,3)
>> B(1)
ans = 
    a: 1
    b: 2
    c: []

>> B(2)
ans = 
    a: []
    b: []
    c: []

>> B(3)
ans = 
    a: []
    b: 10
    c: 11
```